# Split high resolution image for printing

Tags: images, printing, high-resolution

I have a 9493*13259 pixel .png file that I want to print.  The problem is that the details in that image will be too small if I print it on one piece of paper.  The maximum paper size that my printer can print is A4,so I can not use bigger paper for printing.

Is there a way to split a high resolution image into a number of tiles or sections, print those pieces, and then stitch the prints together to form the whole image?

Comment: Most printer drivers have this functionality, for things like poster printing. Not ideal because, as you say, you have to then "stitch" the sheets together and, due to the printer not being able to print to the paper edge, you often have to cut the excess off! What OS are you using?

Comment: @BigChris I use windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: Take it to a print/copy shop? Our local shop will take emailed files. Then I walk there and discuss the printing with them - size/paper type etc.

Comment: @DavidPostill I search for a way to use my printer,because I usually have to use such high resolution images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can convert this image to a PDF (or print it to a PDF printer), then, when printing the PDF with Adobe Reader, you have an option of poster printing. The program can automatically split the content across multiple pages with configurable overlap and cut marks.

Answer (score 1):

Use MS Paint, in page set up you can choose fit to option and fit your picture in 2,4 or multiples 2 number of pages. By removing the margin you can print up to the edge of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe photoshop crop option to split the image then print it then use some cello tape to join it

Comment: `Adobe photoshop` is not free App.